# trying to add dynamic integer value to dynamic id generated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a dynamic integer value to dynamic id generated while clicking on btnExport .I am incrementing `var i` on each click and then assigning its value to dynamically generated textboxes.Any idea would be appreciated.

```
$("#btnExport").after(s);
var i = 0;
$('#btnASize').click(function () {
    i += 1;
    var sizerangeMin = "<input type='text' ID='SizeMin''+i+' value='2.00' />";
    var ToleranceMin = "<input type='text' ID='TolMin'+i value='1' />";
    var ToleranceMax = "<input type='text' ID='TolMax'+i value='1' />";
    var markup = "<tr><td>" + sizerangeMin + "</td><td>" + ToleranceMin + "</td><td>" + ToleranceMax + "</td></tr>";
    $("#WireDimTbl tbody").append(markup); 
});
```

But this code doesn't show the value of my variable.

Comment: What's your questions? Is there an error? Is there unexpected behavior?

Comment: you are not properly concatenating your `i` variable

Comment: This problem is a simple type error `'+i+'` should be `"+i+"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you are including your variable right inside a string.

The correct code is:

```
var sizerangeMin = "<input type='text' ID='SizeMin'" + i + " value='2.00' />";
var ToleranceMin = "<input type='text' ID='TolMin'" + i + " value='1' />";
var ToleranceMax = "<input type='text' ID='TolMax'"+ i + "value='1' />";
```

Also, you can use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) if your browser supports ES6.

In that case, you can use your variables directly inside strings without concatenation.

```
var age = 25;

var ageStr = `I am ${age} years old.`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add dynamic Ids like below example.

```
  var sizerangeMin =  "<input type='text' ID='SizeMin'"+i+" value='2.00' />"
```